# How to marshal/unmarshal a Map<Integer, List<Integer>>?

Tags: java, jaxb, moxy

The following program marshals and unmarshals a class containing a `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>` field.

After unmarshaling the list in the map contains **strings** and not integers.

**Is there an easy way to ensure that the list will be filled with integers instead of
strings during unmarshalling?**

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.MarshallerProperties;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.MediaType;

public class MapApp {

    @XmlRootElement
    public static class Publication {

        private String name;

        private Map<Integer, List<Integer>> yearToIssues;

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setYearToIssues(Map<Integer, List<Integer>> yearToIssues) {
            this.yearToIssues = yearToIssues;
        }

        public Map<Integer, List<Integer>> getYearToIssues() {
            return yearToIssues;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        Publication publication = new Publication();
        publication.setName("JAXB miracles");
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> yearToIssues = new HashMap<>();
        yearToIssues.put(2013, Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12));
        yearToIssues.put(2014, Arrays.asList(1, 2));
        publication.setYearToIssues(yearToIssues);
        String marshalled = marshal(publication);
        Publication uPublication = unmarshal(Publication.class, marshalled);
        List<Integer> issues = uPublication.getYearToIssues().get(2013);
        if (((Object) issues.get(0)) instanceof String) {
            System.out.println("issue is instance of String!");
        }

    }

    static String marshal(Object toMarshal) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] {toMarshal.getClass()}, null);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        marshaller.marshal(toMarshal, sw);
        System.out.println(sw);
        return sw.toString();
    }

    static <T> T unmarshal(Class<T> entityClass, String str) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] {entityClass}, null);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
        return (T) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(str));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to need to write an `XmlAdapter` for `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>` to properly handle this use case.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html

Comment: Thx, so i implemented a XmlAdapter, marshalling the map to a String and vice versa.
Format looks like that:

2013:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12;2014:1,2